# Is there any way to train numpy neural networks faster?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I implemented a Neural Network class using only python and numpy, and I want to do some experiments with it. The problem is that it takes so long to train. My computer does not have a high-end GPU nor a wonderful CPU, so I thought about some sort of 'cloud training'.

I know libraries such as TensorFlow or PyTorch use backends to train neural networks faster, and I was wondering if something similar could be achieved with numpy. Is there a way to run numpy in the cloud?

Even if it is slow and doesn't use GPUs would be fine for me. I tried to load my files to Google Colab, but it didn't work so well. It stopped running due to inactivity after some time.

Is there any nice solution out there?

Thanks for reading it all!

Comment: _Is there any way to train numpy neural networks faster?_ Yes, performance can almost always be improved. _Is there a way to run numpy in the cloud?_ Yes, what exactly do you mean? _I tried to load my files to Google Colab, but it didn't work so well. It stopped running due to inactivity after some time._ I can't remember the exact details, but Google Colab being a free service does have certain limits/restrictions in place related to the run time and requirements of the programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [cupy](https://cupy.chainer.org/) instead of numpy, it runs on GPU (works well on colab GPU instance) and maybe you should do just some little modifications to your code.